# How do I check to see if a character is a space character in Swift?

Tags: string, swift, character, spaces

In a program I'm writing, I need to check to see if a character is a space (" "). Currently have this as the conditional but it's not working. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
for(var k = indexOfCharBeingExamined; k < lineBeingExaminedChars.count; k++){

    let charBeingExamined = lineBeingExaminedChars[lineBeingExaminedChars.startIndex.advancedBy(k)];

//operations

    if(String(charBeingExamined) == " "){

    //more operations

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add how charBeingExamined is being declared and the context of your code

Answer (score 4):

The code below is how I solved this problem with a functional approach in Swift. I made an extension (two, actually), but you could easily take the guts of the function and use it elsewhere.

```
extension String {
    
    var isWhitespace: Bool {
        guard !isEmpty else { return true }
        
        let whitespaceChars = NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines
        
        return self.unicodeScalars
            .filter { !whitespaceChars.contains($0) }
            .count == 0
    }
    
}

extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    
    var isNullOrWhitespace: Bool {
        return self?.isWhitespace ?? true
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It's perhaps better to use `contains` instead of `filter`, since it's cheaper.

Comment: In Swift `5.2` explicit types no longer seem to be required.

Answer (score 3):

The following code works for me. Note that it's easier to just iterate over the characters in a string using 'for' (second example below):

```
var s = "X yz"
for var i = 0; i < s.characters.count; i++ {
    let x = s[s.startIndex.advancedBy(i)]
    print(x)
    print(String(x) == " ")
}

for c in s.characters {
    print(c)
    print(String(c) == " ")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**String:**

```
let origin = "Some string with\u{00a0}whitespaces" // \u{00a0} is a no-break space
```

**Oneliner:**

```
let result = origin.characters.contains { " \u{00a0}".characters.contains($0) }
```

**Another approach:**

```
let spaces = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()
let result = origin.utf16.contains { spaces.characterIsMember($0) }
```

---

**Output:**

```
print(result) // true
```

Not sure what you want to do with the spaces, because then it could be a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

just in your code change **" "** ->  **"\u{00A0}"**

```
for(var k = indexOfCharBeingExamined; k < lineBeingExaminedChars.count; k++){
    let charBeingExamined = lineBeingExaminedChars[lineBeingExaminedChars.startIndex.advancedBy(k)];
    if(String(charBeingExamined) == "\u{00A0}"){
        //more operations
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To test just for whitespace:

```
func hasWhitespace(_ input: String) -> Bool {
    let inputCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: input)
    
    return !inputCharacterSet.intersection(CharacterSet.whitespaces).isEmpty
}
```

To test for both whitespace and an empty string:

```
func hasWhitespace(_ input: String) -> Bool {
    let inputCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: input)
    
    return !inputCharacterSet.intersection(CharacterSet.whitespaces).isEmpty || inputCharacterSet.isEmpty
}
```